# How can I customize each row of Android ListView?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, customization

I would like to know if it's possible to customize each row of listview? I want to add checkboxes to few of the rows, button for another, etc. How to build *.xml file for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes its possible .you can search web there are numerous tutorials for this.You will be wasting your time for someone to answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476217/two-views-in-each-list-item/8476380#8476380

The principle's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a normal layout file like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/lineItem">
  <!-- The attribute name -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/attributeName" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:textStyle = "bold" android:paddingTop = "2dp" android:textSize="16dp"/>

  <!-- The attribute value just beneath the attribute name -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/attributeValue" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@id/attributeName" android:textSize="12dp"  android:paddingBottom="2dp" />

  <!-- Now create button besides the line with right align -->
  <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:background="@drawable/printbutton" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/printbtn" 
  android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your listview adapter function

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

you can use the line

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewrow,null);
```

This is what i have done.

Answer (score 1):

RFTM [Android custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) and [binding data to a view](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html)

That leads to creating a custom Adapter (probably from `ListAdapter` or  `ArrayAdapter`).

You can also start with a ListActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah!It's possible to customize each row with a your layout.(also with CheckBox)
You need to develop a custom ArrayAdapter. 
You may find a tutorial [here](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/):

I hope it will be useful for you.