# Adding ImageView to a ListView

Tags: android, imageview, android-listview

I have a class that extends Activity and inflates another xml layout in the main layout.

Example:

```
public class PrivateHistory extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);  

    viewBundleMessage();

    LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.menu_linear_layout);
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_list, null);
    item.addView(child);

    getHistoryInfo();

    }
}
```

Example (menu_list layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listViewMenu">

</ListView>
```

And there is a getHistoryInfo method that I'm using to retrieve some history information from the db so I can put every record in a ListItem.

Example:

```
public void getHistoryInfo(){

//removed historyItem + database information

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMenu);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.history_list_view, historyItem));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            showToast(historyItem.get(position).toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Example (history_list_view):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/noteText"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="14dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_white_grey"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:typeface="serif"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

So everything here works, but only if you want to add text into every ListItem. I would like to add images to every ListItems, but how? If this class had extended a ListActivity it wouldn't be that hard, but it extends an Activity. So can anyone help me here?

For anyone that would like to use my app, please go to:
http://www.4shared.com/android/tWfbNqZ6/Free_Wallet.html

Comment: if you google you will get a lot.

Comment: see here they will post only links not more than you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have customized rows for the list (i.e. anything other than a textview) you should create your own [adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)-implementation. Here is another answer (by me) explaining the general principle:
[Two views in each list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476217/two-views-in-each-list-item/8476380#8476380) (the example is about two textviews rather than an image, but just replace the layout with two textview for a layout with an imageview and change the corresponding lines in the getView() method)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom `BaseAdapter` where in the `getView()` method you can inflate your custom View for a list item. For more information you can check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html or here: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/

Hope this helps for now! In case you have any specific problem, please shoot it!

Comment: Thanx, I'll take the time to understand how BaseAdapter works. I appreciate your and the others effort for posting helpful information here.

Comment: Your welcome! In case you need anything, we all be glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You have write a custom adapter for the list view. Do one thing read something about BASE ADAPTER.

[Here is the link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to depend on the historyItem, you must use your own adapter implementation as outlined by Jave.

However, if you simply want a bullet or similar in the list item, you can change the history_list_view to a more complex layout including different Layout objects, ImageViews and the TextView which is mandatory when using ArrayAdapter.
With the enhanced history_list_view, you can use `ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)`, which you will call with

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.history_list_view,
    R.id.noteText, historyItem));
```

Comment: Well, I tried to change the history_list_view.xml file by adding the TextView and ImageView in a RelativeLayout and got error message (didn't take the time to read the error log). Maybe if you write a small example, it will work, idk...