# How to display four buttons and a textview in listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my first project in android and I want to display something like this in list view
Any advice is appreciated

[image]

Comment: You can easily achieve it through Custom Adapters.The  interesting thing will be changing image based on row number

Answer (score 2):

You can go through CustomListView example.it can be done easily.
Please go through the Link below
[how to customize listview row android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407865/how-to-customize-listview-row-android)

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this layout you should use custom listview for that like it.

A row with one text view and four button mean five object in each row but show only two object one is textview and another is one button out or four button.
If you want to display fourth button then invisible first there button and fourth button in visible state.
If you want to display second button then first, third and fourth button invisible state only second button in visible state. 
Fallow this logic in each row.
I hope you got you answer after using this logic.