# issue is maintain state of multipal checkbox in single row of listview android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have googling before asking this, i got few good answer like [Android: CursorAdapter, ListView and CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803756/android-cursoradapter-listview-and-checkbox/4804366#4804366) etc,
but i need multipal checkbox in single row of listview,now my question is how can i maintain state of it

[image: MY issue is how to maintain state of multipal checkbox in single row]

Comment: Simple, assign different id to checkbox and implement setOnClickListener to those checkboxes. Now using id you can maintain the state of each checkbox.

Comment: @user370305 thnx for reply, as ur direction i ve taken checkbox dynamically and assigned ids, now i m bit confusing for how to use id to maintain state

Comment: Now when you register onClickListener to it. And when any CheckBox is clicked you can get the which CheckBox is clicked by its id using `view.getId()` and do whatever you want.

Comment: solved by maintaining array thanks

Comment: Welcome Buddy..! Happy Coding..! Also If possible Maintain the state of CheckBox along with List Item row's data so In feature it will never go wrong. (By creating Custom Class List Array )

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need a custom adapter. Override the `getView` to return a `View` with three boxes. The following links should help:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom
2. [how to customize listview row android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407865/how-to-customize-listview-row-android)
3. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/