# How to add multiple fields in AutoCompleteTextView in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Hi i am very new for android and in my app i have add AutoCompleteTextView ok that's fine

But here my main requirement is i want to add multiple fields in AutoCompleteTextView

like planets,colors,rupees string array-lists i want to display in my AutoCompleteTextView like below image

and when i tapped on AutoCompleteTextView any row that data have to display in one Textview

and i am totally confusing because i am very new for android how to do this please help me

### MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AutoCompleteTextView  autoCompleteTextView;

    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
            "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};

    String[] colors = new String[] { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow",
            "Orange", "Cyan", "Black", "Megenta"};

    String[] Ruppes = new String[] { "100", "200", "300", "400",
            "500", "600", "700", "800"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.AutoCompletion);
       // Conutry_Names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,planets);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

### my xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/AutoCompletion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:hint="@string/Enter_Name_Here"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Compose_message extends Fragment {

    Context con;
    CustomAutoCompleteTextView to;
    public static SQLiteDatabase simpledb=null;
    public static String dbname="your database name";
    String tablename="user";
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        con=this.getActivity();
        simpledb=con.openOrCreateDatabase(dbname, con.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_compose_message, container, false);
       to=(CustomAutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.comose_to);
       to.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor c=simpledb.rawQuery("select id,first_name,last_name,city from '"+tablename+"' where first_name like '%"+to.getText().toString()+"%' ",null);
                    aList.clear();                 
                   if(c.getCount()>0)
                   {
                       c.moveToFirst();
                       do
                       {
                           HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                           hm.put("id", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
                           hm.put("first_name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("first_name")));
                           hm.put("last_name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("last_name"))+" <");
                           hm.put("city", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("city"))+" >");
                           aList.add(hm);

                       }while(c.moveToNext());
                       String[] from = {"first_name","last_name","city"};
                       int[] to1 = { R.id.first_name,R.id.last_name,R.id.city};
                       SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(con, aList, R.layout.autocomplete_layout, from, to1);
                       to.setAdapter(adapter);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                   }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
     return rootView;

    }
}

/*CustomAutoCompleteTextView class */
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    String name;
    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /** Returns the country name corresponding to the selected item */
    @Override
    protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
        /** Each item in the autocompetetextview suggestion list is a hashmap object */
        HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedItem;

        for(String key:hm.keySet())
        {
             name=(String)hm.get("first_name")+" ";
             name+=(String)hm.get("last_name")+" ";
             name+=(String)hm.get("city");
        }

        return name;
    }
}

/* autocomplate layout*/
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:background="@color/white"
     >


    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" 
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@color/white"           
    />  
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" 
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@color/white"           
    />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/last_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" 
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"    
            android:background="@color/white"       
    />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" 
            android:padding="2dp"   
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
             android:background="@color/white"        
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

While building the `adapter` you can combine the values as required:
Ex:

```
String[] keywords;

counter =0;
for(i=0; i< palnets.length(); i++)
{
  for(j=0; j< colors.length(); j++)
  {
   keywords[counter] = "Planet" + planets[i] + "Color:" + colors[j] + "Price:" + prices[j];
   counter++;
  }
}

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, keywords);
    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what is this keywords?

Comment: please clearly Explain including with Xml file i am very new for this tecjnology

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that `keywords` is a `String[]` variable. I've edited my answer accordingly.
I've used your example only to give the answer. You can use similar code modifying as your need. Put my given code inside `onCreate()`. I don't think any modification required in XML file.

Comment: To customize the view I think you can follow another discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407865/how-to-customize-listview-row-android)

Comment: nullPointerArray exception is coming

Comment: You can check if all arrays are initialized before the loops.
Just found that we need to add one more counter for increasing `keywords` instead of depending on `i and j`. Updated the code accordingly. I hope it should work.